# Change a script into a function so that it can be looped. The script uses mutate and str_detect to create a new data frame column

Tags: r, tidyr, stringr

I have a large data frame (462K rows), with a variable listing the generic drug name contents of medicines. There are thousands of different generic drugs; I am interested in about 100 of them. Some medicines have multiple generic drug components; I need to know if any of the drugs I am interested in are contained in the medicine. I have created a script that adds a new logical variable to the data frame with mutate, which is TRUE if one of the generic drugs, e.g., "ibuprofen" is present, either by itself or in combination with other generic drugs using str_detect.

I would like to turn this script into a function so that I can loop it through a list of drugs of interest instead of copying and editing the script for each drug of interest.

Here is the script, which works and in this instance will find the character pattern DICLOFEN in the data frame column drug_generic_name and create a new column in the data frame called Diclofenac:

```
Drug_Table_Names <- data.frame(mutate(Drug_Table_Names, DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, 
                                  Diclofenac = str_detect 
                                  (Drug_Table_Names$DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,"DICLOFEN", negate = FALSE)))
```

I believe that the function I want will have two arguments: 1. An argument for mutate which will be the name of the variable it will create, Diclofenac in the example above. 2. An argument for str_detect, to detect, i.e. the generic name of the drug (or part of it, in this instance), in the example above DICLOFEN.

I have a two column tibble, NSAID_LIST, with two variables, drug_flag which will be the name of the new variable and gen_name which is the pattern that str_detect will look for:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  drug_flag    gen_name    
  <chr>        <chr>       
1 Diclofenac   DICLOFENAC  
2 Fenoprofen   FENOPROFEN  
3 Flurbiprofen FLURBIPROFEN
4 Ibuprofen    IBUPROFEN   
5 Ketoprofen   KETOPROFEN  
6 Naproxen     NAPROXEN    

Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   13 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ drug_flag: chr  "Diclofenac" "Fenoprofen" "Flurbiprofen" "Ibuprofen" ...
 $ gen_name : chr  "DICLOFENAC" "FENOPROFEN" "FLURBIPROFEN" "IBUPROFEN" ...
```

Here is my failed attempt at writing the function which I have called FlagDrugNames:

```
FlagDrugNames<-function (drug_flag, gen_name) {Drug_Table_Names <- data.frame(mutate(Drug_Table_Names, DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, 
                                     drug_flag = str_detect 
                                     (Drug_Table_Names$DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,
                                       "gen_name", negate = FALSE)))}
```

I have two problems:
First, the function doesn't work (or I don't know how to use it). When I run the function and type in the arguments:

```
FlagDrugNames(Flurbiprofen, FLURBIPROFEN)
```

It doesn't add a new column to the data frame the way the script does.

Second: I would like to run this function through the list of gen_name and drug_flag values in the tibble shown above.

I would be grateful for help with writing the function and then being ale to pass the drug_flag and gen_name pairs to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using the mtcars set as an example, something like this could work:

```
find_names = function(dat, col1, string1, new_col_name) {

    mutate_call = lazyeval::interp(~ str_detect(a,string1), a = as.name(col1))

    dat %>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), new_col_name))

    return(dat)

  }

mtcars = find_names(mtcars, 'wt', '2', 'ibuprofen')
```

Then, you use a for loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dict) { find_names(mtcars,'wt',dict[i,1],dict[i,2]) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I got an error message with the find_names function. mutate_() is deprecated. 
Please use mutate() instead

The 'programming' vignette or the tidyeval book can help you
to program with mutate() : https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org
This warning is displayed once per session.

Comment: The loop code gave the following error: 
Error: unexpected '{' in "for (i in 1:nrow(dict) {"> find_names = function(dat, col1, string1, new_col_name) {mutate_call = lazyeval::interp(~ str_detect(a,string1), a = as.name(col1))   dat %>% mutate(.dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), new_col_name)) }

Comment: one other problem: the function worked to create the new variable but it did not add the variable to the original data frame, which I need to do.

Comment: fixed to assign change to dataframe